# Cent OS firewall Problem with Services (Jenkins and Apache Tomcat) deployed on servers

Tags: jenkins, centos, firewall

I have Deployed Jenkins On a Server. The Server runs a CentOS Linux 8 as Operating system. I Wanted to access the Jenkins from another Device (laptop/PC) which is already in same network. but firewall restricts me in doing this. whenever i disable firewall I'm able to access the Jenkins but disabling firewall isn't option for me what else can i do to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to open the ports used by Jenkins in the Centos Firewall. As I understand Jenkins uses ports 8080 and 8443 by default. See this [guide on how to open and close ports in Centos 8](https://linuxconfig.org/redhat-8-open-and-close-ports)

Answer (score 0):

You can open the ports used by Jenkins/Tomcat using this command:

```
firewall-cmd --perm --add-port=your-port/your-protocol for example, to open port 8080 in tcp use this
firewall-cmd --perm --add-port=8080/tcp
```

After doing that, you have to reload the FirewallD tables using:

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

The `--perm` option makes your rule permanent upon reboot.